# Access a shared folder from Android

Tags: nas, android, shared-folders

i have a NAS (SilverStore 2-Drive NAS) in which i store all my FullHD video recordings.

The NAS shares the folders as public.

In fact from my windows 8 pc i can access them using Windows Explorer at this address:

```
\\192.168.48.100\Public\Videos
```

I have an Android mini pc connected to my TV and I would like to access my videos from there.

Anyway when I try with Android Explorer 192.168.48.100 is found as a network place, but if i try to open it it says "try another username/password?"

How to access from Android a shared folder that from Windows is seen as public?

Comment: What's "Android Explorer"? Do you mean the default Web browser? Have you tried a file system app like ASTRO or ES File Explorer?

Comment: This might be helpful: [Access PC using tablet](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/10953)

Comment: What is the protocol?  SMB, NFS?  Try Es file explorer?  Or search google play for a network media player until you find one that uses the file sharing protocol your NAS is using so you can directly browse the network location from the media player.

Comment: @Damon it is SMB, but i found a way to access, see my own answer

Comment: @AlEverett By "explorer" i mean the an app called "Eplorer" (wtih white icon made of paper boxes) that was alerady installed on my device. It is a tool to browse local folders, sd cards, usb and network places.

Comment: Ah. That must be specific to the Android mini-pc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I found the solution.

The protocol was SMB so to access a public file i found out i had to type user guest and passsword guest.

After that it worked.

And on next connection attempts i could also login using the "anonymous" flag in the login screen. I don't know if this a bug of the Explorer (this is the name) app i am using, anyway my problem was solved by using guest/guest.

Comment: Could you please share links, how do we achieve programatically.